# Decorator design: executing a method only if it has been overridden

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

I've stumbled in a tricky python question. Given (**updated**):

```
class A(object):
    def run(self):
        # This makes possible to determine if 'run' was overridden
        if self.run.im_func != A.run.im_func:
            print('Running in {0}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))

class B(A):
    def run(self):
        super(B, self).run()

class C(A):
    pass

b = B()
c = C() 
b.run()
>>> Running in B

c.run()
>>> # nothing :)
```

How would you design the @runoverriden decorator, that would do the job of conditional statement in A.run()?

**Update:**
The purpose of this code is that A.run() should log the run() calls , only if it has been overridden.

Thank you!

Comment: I gave an answer which I think is what you asked for, but can you update the question to explain why you want it? It may be that there is a better and simpler solution to give you what you want rather than what you asked.

Comment: It seems like you can simply change your class hierarchy so that "non-overridden" means "superclass" means "the body of the superclass method is just `pass`".  Why do all this work when you could simply re-ordering of the super-class sub-class relationships?

Comment: @Duncan, I've updated the question details. If you're still interested, could you please take a look?

Comment: While you have an answer that works, I think you should seriously consider what @S.Lott is saying. Put another way, it seems like you're going about this backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want:

```
import functools
def runoverridden(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        if getattr(self, f.__name__).im_func != wrapper:
            return f(self, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper

class A(object):
    @runoverridden
    def run(self):
        print('Running in A')

class B(A):
    def run(self):
        super(B, self).run()
        print('Running in B')

class C(A):
    pass

b = B()
c = C() 
b.run()
c.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). Specifically, the [abstractmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) decorator.

Comment: Thanks, close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. ABCMeta will throw an exception on code "building" stage. While @runoverriden should stop the base class method call, if it finds out that the method was not overridden in a child class. Bottomline - a fake method call.